# How to push latin-2 chracters from mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding, windows-1252

I have a mysql database of "products" and I am pushing them to an app via this .php code. My Problem is, that because I have special characters such as "ä,ö,ü" and especially "€", this code does not work for me. Special Characters are just deleted out of the String.

I have tried several encodings in the php and have tried uploading the data to the database in windows 1252 as well as latin 1, 2, 15.

Results can be seen here: arsdecora.net/get_all.php

```
<?php
/*
* Following code will list all the products
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM table") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    $product["kategorie"] = $row["kategorie"];
    $product["beschreibung"] = $row["beschreibung"];
$product["bild"] = $row["bild"];
    $product["preis"] = $row["preis"];

$products[] = array_map(function ($string) { return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8'); }, $product);
}
$data = array(
//'success'   => 1,
'products' => $products
);

   }
echo json_encode($data); // make it slightly more readable
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> windows 1252 as well as latin 1, 2, 15

To allow multiple encodings you must switch to utf8.  And do it at all stages of your code.

Comment: Well, I have the data on in a mysql Database. I retrieve it from the php with this:                     

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

and I altered the code above to both utf-8. Still the php is returning only what looks like latin-1.

Comment: `<meta ... charset=UTF-8>` in html.  `CHARACTER SET utf8` in column/table.